# How to use MySQLTuner on Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysqltuner

I've installed [MySQLTuner](http://mysqltuner.com/) locally and it works on my local database.

When I try to run it on my Amazon RDS db it does not, it says my login credentials are invalid.

```
$ perl mysqltuner.pl --host testing-db.??????????.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port 3306 --user admin_un --password admin_pw --forcemem 7500
[--] Performing tests on testing-db.??????????.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
[!!] Attempted to use login credentials, but they were invalid
```

I'm able to `myssql` normally into the RDS db locally with.

```
mysql -h testing-db.??????????.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u admin_un -p
```

What could I be missing here?

**UPDATE**

The DB is on an [AWS RDS db.m3.large](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html)    instance which has 2 vCPUs and 7.5GiB of RAM.  I've configured the MySQL configuration settings as suggested [here](http://www.mgt-commerce.com/blog/magento-on-steroids-best-practice-for-highest-performance/) in an RDS Parameter Group from the AWS console.

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1
autocommit  ON
automatic_sp_privileges ON
back_log    170
basedir /rdsdbbin/mysql/
big_tables  OFF
bind_address    *
binlog_cache_size   32768
binlog_checksum CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_error_action IGNORE_ERROR
binlog_format   MIXED
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery OFF
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
binlog_order_commits    ON
binlog_row_image    FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events    OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
binlogging_impossible_mode  IGNORE_ERROR
block_encryption_mode   aes-128-ecb
bulk_insert_buffer_size 67108864
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.23.R1/share/charsets/
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert   AUTO
connect_timeout 10
core_file   OFF
datadir /rdsdbdata/db/
date_format %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size  1000
disconnect_on_expired_password  ON
div_precision_increment 4
end_markers_in_json OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency    OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit   10
error_count 0
event_scheduler OFF
expire_logs_days    0
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp ON
external_user   
flush   OFF
flush_time  0
foreign_key_checks  ON
ft_boolean_syntax   + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 4
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ft_stopword_file    (built-in)
general_log OFF
general_log_file    /rdsdbdata/log/general/mysql-general.log
group_concat_max_len    1024
gtid_executed   
gtid_mode   OFF
gtid_next   AUTOMATIC
gtid_owned  
gtid_purged 
have_compress   YES
have_crypt  YES
have_dynamic_loading    YES
have_geometry   YES
have_openssl    YES
have_profiling  YES
have_query_cache    YES
have_rtree_keys YES
have_ssl    YES
have_symlink    YES
host_cache_size 633
identity    0
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
ignore_db_dirs  
init_connect    
init_file   
init_slave  
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 8388608
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF
innodb_api_trx_level    0
innodb_autoextend_increment 512
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 5705302016
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering all
innodb_checksum_algorithm   innodb
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5
innodb_compression_level    6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    /rdsdbdata/db/innodb
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format  Antelope
innodb_file_format_check    ON
innodb_file_format_max  Antelope
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  2
innodb_flush_method O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors  1
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table 
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  8388608
innodb_log_compressed_pages ON
innodb_log_file_size    134217728
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   /rdsdbdata/log/innodb
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1
innodb_monitor_disable  
innodb_monitor_enable   
innodb_monitor_reset    
innodb_monitor_reset_all    
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728
innodb_open_files   2000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
innodb_page_size    16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_threads    1
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  4
innodb_read_only    OFF
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_status_output    OFF
innodb_status_output_locks  OFF
innodb_strict_mode  OFF
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_thread_concurrency   6
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   0
innodb_undo_directory   .
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio   ON
innodb_use_sys_malloc   ON
innodb_version  5.6.23
innodb_write_io_threads 4
insert_id   0
interactive_timeout 28800
join_buffer_size    8388608
keep_files_on_create    OFF
key_buffer_size 16777216
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit    100
large_files_support ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages OFF
last_insert_id  0
lc_messages en_US
lc_messages_dir /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.23.R1/share/
lc_time_names   en_US
license GPL
local_infile    ON
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
locked_in_memory    OFF
log_bin ON
log_bin_basename    /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog
log_bin_index   /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog.index
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events   OFF
log_error   /rdsdbdata/log/error/mysql-error.log
log_output  TABLE
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF
log_slave_updates   ON
log_slow_admin_statements   OFF
log_slow_slave_statements   OFF
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes  0
log_warnings    1
long_query_time 10.000000
low_priority_updates    OFF
lower_case_file_system  OFF
lower_case_table_names  0
master_info_repository  TABLE
master_verify_checksum  OFF
max_allowed_packet  16777216
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 134217728
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors  100
max_connections 604
max_delayed_threads 20
max_error_count 64
max_heap_table_size 268435456
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   18446744073709551615
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    18446744073709551615
metadata_locks_cache_size   1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances   8
min_examined_row_limit  0
multi_range_count   256
myisam_data_pointer_size    6
myisam_max_sort_file_size   10737418240
myisam_mmap_size    18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options  OFF
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 134217728
myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap OFF
net_buffer_length   16384
net_read_timeout    30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout   60
new OFF
old OFF
old_alter_table OFF
old_passwords   0
open_files_limit    65535
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on
optimizer_trace enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features    greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit   1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size    16384
optimizer_trace_offset  -1
performance_schema  OFF
performance_schema_accounts_size    -1
performance_schema_digests_size -1
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  -1
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   -1
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  -1
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size   -1
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   -1
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    -1
performance_schema_hosts_size   -1
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   -1
performance_schema_max_file_classes 50
performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances   -1
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    200
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   40
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances -1
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances -1
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes    168
performance_schema_max_table_handles    -1
performance_schema_max_table_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances -1
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   -1
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    100
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   100
performance_schema_users_size   -1
pid_file    /rdsdbdata/log/mysql-3306.pid
plugin_dir  /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.23.R1/lib/plugin/
port    3306
preload_buffer_size 32768
profiling   ON
profiling_history_size  15
protocol_version    10
proxy_user  
pseudo_slave_mode   OFF
pseudo_thread_id    2101
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   2097152
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    67108864
query_cache_type    OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
rand_seed1  0
rand_seed2  0
range_alloc_block_size  4096
read_buffer_size    2097152
read_only   OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    16777216
relay_log   /rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog
relay_log_basename  /rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog
relay_log_index /rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog.index
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository   TABLE
relay_log_purge ON
relay_log_recovery  ON
relay_log_space_limit   0
report_host 
report_password 
report_port 3306
report_user 
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
secure_auth ON
secure_file_priv    /tmp/
server_id   728071541
server_id_bits  32
server_uuid 3b5e219e-4d6b-11e5-865c-0aa85b481d31
simplified_binlog_gtid_recovery OFF
skip_external_locking   ON
skip_name_resolve   OFF
skip_networking OFF
skip_show_database  OFF
slave_allow_batching    OFF
slave_checkpoint_group  512
slave_checkpoint_period 300
slave_compressed_protocol   OFF
slave_exec_mode STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir   /rdsdbdata/tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824
slave_net_timeout   3600
slave_parallel_workers  0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max 16777216
slave_rows_search_algorithms    TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors   OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum   ON
slave_transaction_retries   10
slave_type_conversions  
slow_launch_time    2
slow_query_log  OFF
slow_query_log_file /rdsdbdata/log/slowquery/mysql-slowquery.log
socket  /tmp/mysql.sock
sort_buffer_size    262144
sql_auto_is_null    OFF
sql_big_selects ON
sql_buffer_result   OFF
sql_log_bin ON
sql_log_off OFF
sql_mode    NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes   ON
sql_quote_show_create   ON
sql_safe_updates    OFF
sql_select_limit    18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter  0
sql_warnings    OFF
ssl_crl 
ssl_crlpath 
ssl_key /rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/server-key.pem
storage_engine  InnoDB
stored_program_cache    256
sync_binlog 1
sync_frm    ON
sync_master_info    10000
sync_relay_log  10000
sync_relay_log_info 10000
system_time_zone    UTC
table_definition_cache  1400
table_open_cache    2000
table_open_cache_instances  16
thread_cache_size   32
thread_concurrency  10
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    262144
time_format %H:%i:%s
time_zone   UTC
timed_mutexes   OFF
timestamp   1441211575.899966
tmp_table_size  277872640
tmpdir  /rdsdbdata/tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_allow_batching  OFF
transaction_prealloc_size   4096
tx_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only    OFF
unique_checks   ON
updatable_views_with_limit  YES
version 5.6.23-log
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
wait_timeout    28800
warning_count   0


SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
Aborted_clients 0
Aborted_connects    1
Binlog_cache_disk_use   3
Binlog_cache_use    4646
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Bytes_received  333167772
Bytes_sent  951623856
Com_admin_commands  1
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 0
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_alter_user  0
Com_analyze 0
Com_begin   4544
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  0
Com_change_db   6
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  4569
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    0
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  220
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  0
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush   25
Com_get_diagnostics 0
Com_grant   0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  6577
Com_insert_select   0
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   26
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 0
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  700098
Com_set_option  13159
Com_signal  0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_collations 0
Com_show_create_db  0
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   2
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases  0
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 0
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 26
Com_show_function_code  0
Com_show_function_status    1
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   0
Com_show_master_status  0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_code 0
Com_show_procedure_status   1
Com_show_processlist    0
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 36
Com_show_storage_engines    2
Com_show_table_status   8
Com_show_tables 3
Com_show_triggers   0
Com_show_variables  5
Com_show_warnings   0
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_execute    0
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    0
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    0
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   0
Com_update  2463
Com_update_multi    0
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression OFF
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   0
Connection_errors_peer_address  0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
Connections 2106
Created_tmp_disk_tables 45149
Created_tmp_files   9
Created_tmp_tables  113444
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  720775
Handler_delete  5202
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   3139172
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 27492
Handler_read_first  12789
Handler_read_key    5589468
Handler_read_last   7
Handler_read_next   5611704
Handler_read_prev   22934
Handler_read_rnd    1309776
Handler_read_rnd_next   1568679
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  2839
Handler_write   1299654
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   1334
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   21856256
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  0
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    4776
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   346833
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   57
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  348224
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   59
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    39905068
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    1188
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   101088
Innodb_data_fsyncs  3314
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    20500480
Innodb_data_reads   1353
Innodb_data_writes  11652
Innodb_data_written 163682816
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  4776
Innodb_dblwr_writes 1017
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins ON
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   8550
Innodb_log_writes   5612
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    1121
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   7059968
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    88
Innodb_pages_read   1246
Innodb_pages_written    4776
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    0
Innodb_row_lock_waits   0
Innodb_rows_deleted 5202
Innodb_rows_inserted    6552
Innodb_rows_read    9057947
Innodb_rows_updated 2486
Innodb_num_open_files   99
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   13394
Key_blocks_used 12
Key_read_requests   20
Key_reads   14
Key_write_requests  0
Key_writes  0
Last_query_cost 0.000000
Last_query_partial_plans    0
Max_used_connections    9
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  12
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  162
Open_tables 1320
Opened_files    182174
Opened_table_definitions    162
Opened_tables   1346
Performance_schema_accounts_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_digest_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_hosts_lost   0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   0
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_users_lost   0
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  1
Qcache_free_memory  67091104
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   699478
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 1
Queries 733872
Questions   733846
Select_full_join    3775
Select_full_range_join  0
Select_range    159674
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 50953
Slave_heartbeat_period  0.000
Slave_last_heartbeat    
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_received_heartbeats   0
Slave_retried_transactions  0
Slave_running   OFF
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    0
Sort_merge_passes   0
Sort_range  70961
Sort_rows   1330326
Sort_scan   114741
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher  
Ssl_cipher_list 
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0
Ssl_default_timeout 0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_server_not_after    
Ssl_server_not_before   
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  Unknown
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version 
Table_locks_immediate   1565535
Table_locks_waited  0
Table_open_cache_hits   1564338
Table_open_cache_misses 1346
Table_open_cache_overflows  19
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  4
Threads_connected   5
Threads_created 9
Threads_running 1
Uptime  7754
Uptime_since_flush_status   7754
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Observations**

Version: 5.6.23-log
7.5 GB of RAM
Uptime = 02:09:14; Please rerun SHOW GLOBAL STATUS after several hours.
You are not running on Windows.
Running 64-bit version
You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**Important items**

- tmp_table_size = 64M
- Review indexes and query formulation -- many are looking inefficient (by using tmp tables, etc)
- To help in identifying the naughty queries, recommend setting long_query_time=2 and turning on the slowlog.
- Replication is turned on, but the binlogs are being kept forever?  Or does RDS purge them in some way I don't know about.

**Details**

( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free * 16384 / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 346,833 * 16384 / 5705302016 = 99.6% -- % of buffer pool free
-- buffer_pool_size is bigger than working set; could decrease it (not critical)

( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 7,754 / 60 * 128M / 7059968 = 2,456 -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size.
-- Very low activity on your server

( tmp_table_size ) = 265M -- Limit on size of *MEMORY* temp tables used to support a SELECT
( max_heap_table_size / _ram ) = 256M / 7680M = 3.3% -- Percent of RAM to allocate when needing MEMORY table for a temp table inside a SELECT (per temp table per some SELECTs).  Too high may lead to swapping.  (max_heap_table_size also user limits MEMORY tables.)
-- Decrease both to, say, 1% of ram.

( local_infile ) = ON
-- local_infile = ON is a potential security issue

( Created_tmp_disk_tables ) = 45,149 / 7754 = 5.8 /sec -- Frequency of creating *disk* "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs
( Created_tmp_disk_tables / (Created_tmp_disk_tables + Created_tmp_tables) ) = 45,149 / (45149 + 113444) = 28.5% -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Check the rules for temp tables being able to use MEMORY instead of MyISAM. It may be possible to make a minor schema or query change to avoid MyISAM.
Better indexes and reformulation of queries can also help.

-- Decrease tmp_table_size to avoid running out of RAM. Perhaps no more than 64M.

( Select_scan ) = 50,953 / 7754 = 6.6 /sec -- full table scans
( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 50,953 / 700098 = 7.3% -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

( binlog_format ) = MIXED -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED. ROW is preferred; it may become the default.

( expire_logs_days ) = 0 -- How soon to automatically purge binlog (after this many days)
-- Too large (or zero) = consumes disk space; too small = need to respond quickly to network/machine crash.

( slow_query_log ) = OFF -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)
( long_query_time ) = 10.000000 = 10 -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest ON and 2

( Com_flush ) = 12/HR
( Com_purge ) = 12/HR
-- What is doing so many FLUSHes and PURGEs?  These are both rarely-used commands.

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.